# How do I fix the Google play app bundle issue

Tags: flutter

How do  I fix the Google play app bundle issue which stats  the the APK or Andriod App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast reciever with intent filter, but without android: exported property set this file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest. Xml add android exported true like

```dart
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:exported="true"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"
     android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
 </activity>
```